# source ~/.bashrc issue at install

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
quick question, I am sure I will sound dumb, but I prefer to ask as I am starting with ROS.
When I run `source ~/.bashrc` I have the errors below....
Can anyone help me understnad what is going on?

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fbeeae58700 (most recent call first):
bash: /home/jice/cws_oroca/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f6bcd48c700 (most recent call first):
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f3056bb0700 (most recent call first):
jice@jice-System-Product-Name:~$ clear

jice@jice-System-Product-Name:~$ source ~/.bashrc
ROS_DISTRO was set to 'kinetic' before. Please make sure that the environment does not mix paths from different distributions.
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f2fd4c55700 (most recent call first):
ROS_DISTRO was set to 'lunar' before. Please make sure that the environment does not mix paths from different distributions.
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fd0e1165700 (most recent call first):
bash: /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/jice/catkin_ws_oroca/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f23e6f9e700 (most recent call first):
bash: /home/jice/cws_oroca/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f9eb7f46700 (most recent call first):
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

---

Edit: I am trying to remove all of these, thanks for the help, last idea is to reinstall Ubuntu from 0.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279493/source-%7E/.bashrc-issue-at-install/) by [JC](https://answers.ros.org/users/33179/jc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-01-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-11**:
Can you tell us a bit more about your computer? OS (version, how installed, etc)? CPU architecture? How did you install ROS? What Python interpreter do you have installed? Are you using `bash`, or some other shell?

**Comment by [JC](https://answers.ros.org/users/33179/jc/) on 2018-01-28**:
Hi, I am using Ubuntu 16.04, I installed ROS via the info on the wiki here: http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu, but I am sure I did something wrong (was couple of months ago). As well I have Python 3 installed with Anaconda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There seem two be a few different errors in the output you've posted. What version of ROS are you using and have you installed several versions at the same time?

Your **.bashrc** script is trying to execute a package setup script `/home/jice/cws_oroca/devel/setup.bash` but it can't find it at that location. If you check what the actual location is and correct your **.bashrc** then it should fix the first error.

It's also trying to run `/opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` and its failing it find it which looks like you were using indigo but you've upgraded and not changed the path for this file in **.bashrc**

There also seems to be a problem with your python install, or you're trying to use a python library **encodings** that is not installed, or if it is then the path to its location has not been added to the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0